# Trigonometry curiosity

Tags: trigonometry

How prove that:
$$-\tan[(\frac{10\pi}{41}+4[\sin[(\frac{2\pi}{41}+\sin[(\frac{4\pi}{41}+\sin[(\frac{12\pi}{41}+\sin[(\frac{20\pi}{41}-\sin[(\frac{26\pi}{41})]-\sin[(\frac{30\pi}{41})])])])])]])]=\cot[(\frac{2\pi}{41}-\cot[(\frac{8\pi}{41}+\cot[(\frac{20\pi}{41}+\cot[(\frac{32\pi}{41}+\cot⁡[(\frac{36\pi}{41})])])])]$$

Comment: Do you have this written somewhere else?

Comment: @DavidkK Question asked by the same user, but they are different: the one you point to is numerically true, whereas this one is not.